# How to fix browser timeout

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have implemented a basic Client/Server interaction using the `shell_exec();` function in php, which takes the client's link via input and passes to the server using `shell_exec("./script $link");` then calls a script with the link as argument, downloads the file on the server and then returns the link.

However, during that time when the file is downloaded and uploaded, the browser stays in HANGUP waiting for the script to finish and then returns the link.

I would like to know if there is a way to do with what browser are waiting for the script to finish but without entering in HANGUP (a web page still refreshing), because when the link is from some big file, the browser both send requests waiting for the response and after some time returns this error: A TIMEOUT OCCURRED.

It shouldn't necessarily be a full explanation: I just need to know how I can proceed or just get some recommendations or links on this subject.

Comment: You can just do AJAX. Although I think the timeout comes from PHP - the server itself my have a limited execution time of scripts.

Comment: If the full page is refreshing, there shouldn't be any timeout on the browser. It should be a time out on the server, as vlaz mentioned. If you use Ajax, it would be even worse: in that case the browser can time out as well.

Comment: you know what would be useful? *code* - at the moment, we have no idea what you are really doing